# strotime time in php but p not working

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am not sure what mistakes I am making here but for some reason I cannot get %p to display AM or PM.

code:

```
$rep_date= date('D, d M Y - h:i %p', strtotime($overview[0]->date));
```

currently this displays  Wed, 28 May 2014 - 08:27 %p . from my knowledge this supposed to work. any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`%p` is not a valid format parameter for [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). You need `A` for "AM" or "PM" (or `a` for "am" or "pm"):

```
$rep_date= date('D, d M Y - h:i A', strtotime($overview[0]->date));
```

Comment: Thank you. works perfect.. I am confused as here states otherwise. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: That's a MySQL function and cannot be used inside of PHP

Comment: ^--« No "pun" intended, am sure ;-)